# Synchronize Controller with View

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, view, controller

i have a Java project made with mvc where my  flux program is contained on the controller.

I'd like to know how i can synchronize my controller with my view because i suppose that if i need an input for my  swing view my flux program on controller keeps running.

I need help because i don't know how to solve this problem.

I've tried with  blocks containing a boolean (example:while(!Action) that i set in my view and when i return to my controller the variable should be setted (true)).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you want your view be updated when the value change in your controller but you can also change the said value trew your view so that your view must notify the controller to update it's value.

if that is the case

You will need to make your controller listen to a update/change event on your view and update it's data/model according to the view.
You would also need to make a new function for your controler, a new setter. This setter would automaticly update the view and the value each time your controller is directly modified.

```
controller.superSet(newValue)
{
  this.value = newValue;
  view.setValue(newValue);
}
```

Normaly in a MVC, your controller do not hold data (not much atleast) you have a model holding it.  The said model is not suppose to acces the controller or the view directly. he will NOTIFY the controller which will call an update method inside the controller to get the value and update the view.

The controller normally has full acces to the view, but the view does not acces the controller. Views uses event to let know the controller something changed.